# Añadiendo checkbox con append() y cambiar clases

Tags: jquery

Tengo varias capas a las que añado un checkbox con append()

Mi intención es que al hacer click en cada checkbox añada la clase "marcado" o la quite. Tambien que a la capa contenedora añada la clase guardada o la quite.

Estoy empezando a trabajar con estas cosas pero no acabo de comprender por qué no funciona.

```
<div class="ntz">
    <h4>A</h4>
    <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
</div>
<div class="ntz">
    <h4>B</h4>
    <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var insertaCheck = $('<div><input type="checkbox" id="despues"> Guardar</div>');
    $( ".ntz" ).append(insertaCheck);
</script>
<script>
    $('#despues').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).addClass("marcado");
            $(this).parent().addClass("guardada");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('marcado');
            $(this).parent().removeClass("guardada");
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .ntz {background: #f7f7f7; padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}
    .ntz.guardada {background: #9b9b9b; color:#ffffff;}
    h4 {margin:0;color:gold;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No te funciona por dos motivos:

1. El estilo está mal puesto. En lugar de esto:

```css
.ntz.guardada {background: #9b9b9b; color:#ffffff;}
```

Por esto:

```css
.ntz .guardada {background: #9b9b9b; color:#ffffff;}
```

Y ahora empezará a funcionarte, pero cuidado, porque solo estas escuchando el **id** `despues` el cual estás aplicando a varios elementos, por lo tanto, sin más cambios, ahora mismo solo te funcionaria en uno.

**Nota:** El atributo `id` debe ser único en todos los elementos donde se aplique, para no entrar en conflicto con ninguno cuando sea utilizado, pues solo el primero encontrado recibirá sus invocaciones, dejando inservibles a los demas. En cambio, una `clase` (**class=**) sí puede ser común a varios elementos, y es por eso que vamos a usarla para arreglar tu código.

2. La solución es cambiar el `id` por una **clase** común, cambiando esto:

```javascript
var insertaCheck = $('<div><input type="checkbox" id="despues"> Guardar</div>');
```

por esto:

```javascript
var insertaCheck = $('<div><input type="checkbox" class="despues"> Guardar</div>');
```

y luego, modificar esto:

```javascript
$('#despues').click(function(){
```

por esto:

```javascript
$('.despues').click(function(){
```

y ya lo tienes.

Aquí dejo un snippet funcionando con los cambios:

```html
<div class="ntz">
    <h4>A</h4>
    <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
</div>
<div class="ntz">
    <h4>B</h4>
    <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var insertaCheck = $('<div><input type="checkbox" class="despues"> Guardar</div>');
    $( ".ntz" ).append(insertaCheck);
</script>
<script>
    $('.despues').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).addClass("marcado");
            $(this).parent().addClass("guardada");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('marcado');
            $(this).parent().removeClass("guardada");
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .ntz {background: #f7f7f7; padding:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}
    .ntz .guardada {background: #9b9b9b; color:#ffffff;}
    h4 {margin:0;color:gold;}
</style>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!